How do I limit the number of p2p connections in the validator node?
I have a validator node because too many p2p connections are being IP locked by the operator. There are over 2000 total port 30333 connections in and out, I tried it with --in-peers -- out-peers and it didn't work. Does anyone know of a solution?
